# Disabled checkboxes in flowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, flowlayoutpanel

I'm trying to create some checkboxes dynamically in the flowLayoutPanel control.

I have managed to create it but they seem to be disabled inside the panel. I can't check/uncheck them. They are grey and not active.

I suppose there is some flowLayoutPanel property that prevents these checkboxes to be enabled that I'm missing.

Here is my code for **flowLayoutPanel**:

```
// 
// flowLayoutPanelForCheckBoxes
// 
this.flowLayoutPanelForCheckBoxes.Controls.Add(this.SomeCheckBox);
this.flowLayoutPanelForCheckBoxes.AutoScroll = true;
this.flowLayoutPanelForCheckBoxes.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(132, 8);
this.flowLayoutPanelForCheckBoxes.Name = "flowLayoutPanelForCheckBoxes";
this.flowLayoutPanelForCheckBoxes.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(546, 38);
this.flowLayoutPanelForCheckBoxes.TabIndex = 28;
this.flowLayoutPanelForCheckBoxes.WrapContents = false;
```

For generating checkboxes:

```
private List<CheckBox> GetGeneratedCheckboxes()
{
    var generatedCheckboxes = new List<CheckBox>();

    var valuesForCheckboxes = GetCheckboxValuesFromDb(); //it returns dictionary<int, string> 

    // with some numbers and text. I think this method is not as important

    if (valuesForCheckboxes != null && valuesForCheckboxes.Count != 0)
    {
        int index = 0;
        foreach (var chbx in valuesForCheckboxes)
        {
            var checkboxToAdd = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();

            checkboxToAdd.AutoSize = true;
            checkboxToAdd.Enabled = true;
            checkboxToAdd.Checked = true;
            checkboxToAdd.CheckState = System.Windows.Forms.CheckState.Checked;
            checkboxToAdd.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(84, 21);
            checkboxToAdd.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;

            checkboxToAdd.Name = "chboxCountry" + chbx.Key;
            checkboxToAdd.Text = chbx.Value;
            checkboxToAdd.TabIndex = index + 1;

            index++;

            generatedCheckboxes.Add(checkboxToAdd);
        }
    }

    return generatedCheckboxes;
}
```

And it's used in the FormLoad method:

```
var checkboxesForPanel = GetGeneratedCheckboxes();

foreach (var checkbox in checkboxesForPanel)
{
    this.flowLayoutPanelForCheckBoxes.Controls.Add(checkbox);
}
```

Comment: The problem is not reproducible with the information/code you provided; there's something else going on. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Try adding `flowLayoutPanelForCheckBoxes.Enabled = true;` somewhere in your code.

Comment: @preciousbetine didn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: I do not like flowLayoutPanel and rather write my own version using a straight panel.  Many feature like events do not work in the flow panel and many properties are not available.

Comment: My crystal ball says that you see these checkboxes when you opened the designer for a form.  Yes, you can't do anything with them.  Happens when you use the "Inherited Form" item template.  You must use the this.DesignMode property in the base form's Load event handler to avoid executing a dbase query at design-time.  Happens to work now by accident, but you'll have accidents in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Code looks fine for me. It has no issue. Check if your flow layout panel is in disabled state some how. Check in designer or check your code if its getting in disabled state.